# How can I call a .NET web service from PHP?

Tags: php, .net

The web service could be a SOAP asmx or a WCF Service. Assumption here is that the IIS on Windows is serving the web-service and Apache on Linux with PHP 5.3 consuming it.

Comment: This is probably a question for [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: yes, this is a programming question

Comment: should we delete the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hosting system should not matter, calling a web service is the same (in fact, that's one of the points of setting up a web service).

PHP has built in SOAP objects ([Manual Entry for it](http://php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php)).  Those should be able to access it without any issue.